# PHPDocumentator is creating .cs files instead of .css

Tags: css, phpdoc

I've got PHPDocumentator installed and it's almost working as excepted. However, for some reason, it's creating the CSS files as "style.cs", "print.cs", etc. (only one "s"), while these files are referenced as "style.css" etc. in the HTML files.

So is there any way to make PHPDocumentator create all these files with a ".css" extension?

Here is an extract from the creation log:

```
creating s:\xampp\htdocs\idol\doc\/\media
copying s:\xampp\htdocs\idol\doc\/\media/layout.cs
copying s:\xampp\htdocs\idol\doc\/\media/print.cs
copying s:\xampp\htdocs\idol\doc\/\media/style.cs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Laurent: it seems your copy of PHPDocumentator mal-functioned. Please check [this post](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpdocu/forums/forum/35064/topic/4478608).

Comment: wow thanks, I would never have thought it was a wrong build since it's not alpha or beta. I'll give a try to the tar.gz as suggested on the post.